# Passing generic template as an argument

Tags: c#, templates, generics, reusability

Trying to achieve reuse below.

```
if(update)
   var updateType = (A)request;
   updateType.Entity.NameFlag = nameValue;
   updateType.Entity.PhoneFlag = phoneValue
else
   var addType = (B) request;
   addType.Entity.NameFlag = nameValue;
   addType.Entity.PhoneFlag = phoneValue
```

As you can see the only difference is the object (A or B).

How can I use T template to achieve reuse?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void SomeMethod<A,B>()  where A : BaseTypeA where B : BaseTypeB
{
  if(update)
  {
      var updateType = (A)request;
      updateType.Entity.NameFlag = nameValue;
      updateType.Entity.PhoneFlag = phoneValue;
  }
  else
  {
      var addType = (B) request;
      addType.Entity.NameFlag = nameValue;
      addType.Entity.PhoneFlag = phoneValue;
  }
}
```

Try the above

Comment: updated with constraints

Comment: Not sure this really achieves code reuse. Given that A and B do not inherit from the same base class, this is as good as it gets as far as generics though.

Comment: I agree. I would probably also make the argument that the limited code reuse doesn't warrant the extra complexity of base classes and generics.

Comment: @TGH - Can you update the code so 
addType.Entity.NameFlag = nameValue;
addType.Entity.PhoneFlag = phoneValue; can be reuse?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void DoStuff<T>(T item)
   where T : BaseClasseOrInterfaceOfAandB
{       
   item.Entity.NameFlag = nameValue;
   item.Entity.PhoneFlag = phoneValue
}

if(update)
{
    DoStuff((A)request);
}
else
{
    DoStuff((B)request);
}
```

Comment: Can't do this.. i need to cast item so it recognised the Entity object

Comment: Both have different base case and i can't edit/add interface to the base code because it is generated using third party tool.

Comment: You may have noticed that there is a vote to close your question "Too broad". That was me. This is the best guess at an answer based on the very very limit information you give. What are you trying to reuse? What is a "Request"? What and how is "code generated"? Please actually write your pseudo code in the actual target language, or at least describe what on earth that language is.

Comment: @overrule, if they don't inherit from the same base class, generics aren't going to help you much. You could go down the reflection hole, but that is your only hope for "reuse"

Comment: @Aron - the Entity property cannot be resolved unless it is cast. I am implementing what you described.